# JSON Type provider with Deedle (F#): how to read several JSON files on HD?

Tags: f#, type-providers, deedle

suppose i have a lot of files with the **same** JSON format saved on my HD.

i can recover the samples doing the following:

```
type TypeA = JsonProvider<".../Documents/FileA.json">
let sampleA = TypeA.GetSamples()
```

but if i have many files (and for example their name in a list), how do i recover all the samples ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonProvier` supplies a number of methods for parsing runtime supplied data into the data types provided by the type provided:

```
//Load from named file/website
member this.Load(uri: string): this.Root[]
//Load data from stream source
member this.Load(reader: System.IO.TextReader): this.Root[]
member this.Load(stream: System.IO.Stream): this.Root[]

//Load data from named file/website (async)
member this.AsyncLoad(uri: string): Async<this.Root[]>

//Load data directly from string
member this.Parse(text: string): this.Root[]
```

These will all load the relevant data into an array of the type generated from the static parameter of the type provider. For example:

```
open FSharp.Data

type TypeA = JsonProvider<"C:\\DataTemp\\FileA.json">

let directory = "C:\\DataTemp\\"
let files: string[] =
    [|
        "FileA.json"
        "FileB.json"
        "FileC.json"
        "FileD.json"
    |]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let sampleA = TypeA.GetSamples()
    let sampleB = TypeA.Load(directory+"FileB.json")

    let allData = files |> Array.collect (fun f -> TypeA.Load(directory+f))
    for d in allData do
        printfn "%A" d
    //etc

    0
```

Note that these will not always strictly enforce the schema. For example, string type values are allowed to be missing, and will silently be replaced by empty strings; extra data is allowed to be present, and will be loaded into the `JsonValue` data, but inaccessable through the statically typed properties, and so on.